# Pointer-events fail when used on parent element :hover in IE11

Tags: html, css

Here is a snippet of a little navigation structure. If you hover the blue box, a menu will appear revealing new navigation options.

This works in all major browsers except IE11. In IE11 the menu will close once you try to hover it.

The problem is this following CSS:

```
.menu.pointer-events .menu-items
{
    pointer-events: none;
}

.menu.pointer-events:hover .menu-items
{
    pointer-events: initial;
}
```

When i don't use `pointer-events` everyting works ok. But I'd like to use them, as the menu tend to be annoying and is reopening it self. You can see this when you hover in/out in circles at the bottom right corner of the `<a>`.
The menu will "reopen" itself once you touch the `<ul>` that moves up on closing.

Here is a demo, when you hover the links from left to right you should see that the menus blink and don't really seem to know if they should close or not.

```css
.menu
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu > a
{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu .menu-items
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
    margin:0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0 4px 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    min-width: 200%;
    
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    top:-100%;
    transition-property: visibility, opacity, top;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.menu:hover .menu-items,
.menu:focus .menu-items
{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 100%;
}

.menu.pointer-events .menu-items
{
    pointer-events: none;
}

.menu.pointer-events:hover .menu-items,
.menu.pointer-events:focus .menu-items
{
    pointer-events: initial;
}

body
{
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Try to hover these links from forth and back</h1>
<h2>Implementation without pointer events:</h2>
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#">Hover me</a>
    <ul class="menu-items">
        <li>Super</li>
        <li>Duper</li>
        <li>Even more...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#">Then Hover me</a>
    <ul class="menu-items">
        <li>Super</li>
        <li>Duper</li>
        <li>Even more...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#">And then me Hover me</a>
    <ul class="menu-items">
        <li>Super</li>
        <li>Duper</li>
        <li>Even more...</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<hr />
<h2>Implementation with pointer events:</h2>
<div class="menu pointer-events">
    <a href="#">Hover me</a>
    <ul class="menu-items">
        <li>Super</li>
        <li>Duper</li>
        <li>Even more...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu pointer-events">
    <a href="#">Now me</a>
    <ul class="menu-items">
        <li>Super</li>
        <li>Duper</li>
        <li>Even more...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu pointer-events">
    <a href="#">And finally me</a>
    <ul class="menu-items">
        <li>Super</li>
        <li>Duper</li>
        <li>Even more...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is also a link to a jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1411oc9p/3/

### TL/DR

My question is: Why can't i `:hover` my sub menus in IE11? [caniuse.com says IE11 has pointer-events implemented](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) did I forogot something or is there are workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing is because [IE does not support value:initial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)

[image]

you can always try a javascript fix for IE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('mousedown', '.your-class', function (e) {
        $(this).hide();
        var BottomElement = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        $(this).show();
        $(BottomElement).mousedown(); //Manually fire the event for desired underlying element
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/1411oc9p/4/ should have tried this ... :). I'am good without the js fix, as the css delivers a fallback which seems graceful enough.